# Way to track number and type of objects deleted in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is there any way to detect changes made in last `ObjectContext.SaveChanges()` method?

I track the changes myself like update delete and insert of objects, but when there is foreign key relationship, entity framework deletes child references automatically and here I loose tracking.

So for example if I delete a student I track that I have deleted one student.

But when I delete class, it automatically deletes all the students from the class as I have foreign key relationship for them. The problem is I can only track here that one class is deleted but not how many students in the class were deleted.

One way is to count the students of class before deleting it, but that is an unnecessary trip to database.

Is there any other way?

Comment: Let the database audit what happens in the database. You can override `SaveChanges` or subcribe to `OnSavingChanges` (you'll be able to find examples here at SO), but as you see, it's not waterproof and it soon deteriorates into code with lots of `if`s or even reflection, all eating performance. If you work with Sql Server you have various [change tracking options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933875.aspx). These will track cascaded deletes out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ChangeTracker` property on the `DbContext` to find out what Entity Framework will do when `SaveChanges` is called. If you check it *before* you call `SaveChanges` you will get everything that Entity Framework is about to delete or modify.

This assumes that it is indeed *Entity Framework* that does the cascading delete. It might also have been implemented as a cascade delete option on the foreign key in the database. In that case, it's the DB doing the deletes and not EF so the change tracker will not be aware of the pending deletions.

Comment: oh ok! Yes I do have cascade delete for foreign key. Hmm let me check then how it is behaving

Comment: I am using `ObjectContext`, so no `ChangeTracker` for it :(

Comment: With `ObjectContext` you can use `myContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries()`.